# Blog link at foot of security.se pages has incorrect address

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

At the foot of security.stackexchange.com there is a link marked (new) BLOG. Currently this links to blog.stackexchange.com, but I'm thinking it should be to security.blogoverflow.com or possibly just blogoverflow.com. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This has been amended. ♪

The links to your blog, in both the footer and the header, will now redirect to your blog as expected, and will provide apt notice of new blog posts as well.

Answer (score 0):

@Rebecca has mentioned a few times, that since our blog is still in "beta", the link will still point to the main SE blog.
They will agree to change the link to out blog, when the blog goes "live". (When that is or what that means, I do not know...)

Comment: But isn't blog live now? We have full theme, it is front page at blogoverflow etc

Comment: *<shrugs>* Guess you'd have to ask @RebeccaC.